# Use Qemu & chroot to reset password on mounted external disk

Tags: linux, nas, chroot, passwd

I have a NAS based on Linux, but the root password is kept secret by the manufacturer.

Now to reset the password I am trying to mount the disk to my local linux computer. All of the files are present and changing files does affect the system, so I this is the right disk an partition to use.

Next step would be to chroot on the disk and simply do a passwd to change the password for root (since I am already root on the local linux computer). But there is a big problem:

**chroot to the disk is not possible because its architecture is ARM, which differs from my x86 linux computer.**

I heard from ***Qemu*** and its ability to emulate different architectures. Can I emulate **ARM** and use *ARMEL/Debian Linux* inside this **Qemu VM** to mount the **NAS** Hard Disk and make a successful *chroot*?

Is it possible or are there even better solutions. This constellation was pretty rare and badly documented in the world wide web.

Thank you in advance.

---

> This Question is obsolete, since the main problem was solved on another way. Should this post be deleted or kept for historical reasons?

Comment: What is your NAS's make and model? They seriously don't give you root access?

Comment: It is a **Seagate BlackArmor 400** (Identical Software to the other BlackArmors). There are many resources for the SHASTA Board inside, but the root password has been changed and so the resources are outdated. Also I don't want to downgrade to a 2 year older Firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a useful starting point, because it includes instructions for dealing with mirrored drives: http://forums.seagate.com/t5/BlackArmor-NAS-Network-Storage/SSH-root-access-for-BlackArmor-NAS/td-p/108264

A quick and dirty solution if the NAS uses a standard `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files (this depends on its `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as well as its pam configuration in `/etc/pam.conf` and `/etc/pam.d/*`), is to simply delete the root password there: assuming you've mounted the NAS root partition as `/mnt`, then edit `/mnt/etc/shadow` to clear the password field (change a line starting `root:<hashed_password>:...` to `root::...`.

Remember that you absolutely **must** log into the NAS, become root (if you get a password prompt, just hit return) and set a new password before reattaching it to a shared network (let alone the internet), because root has an empty password!

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice starting point and a different point of view. nsswitch.conf is set to look in the **files**, so this should be right. **pam** doesn't exist. Unforunately emptying the root password did not work. Dropbear SSH Server is still denying access to it. I will have a look at dropbear's config now. Maybe empty (or root) login are not allowed...

Comment: The problem has been solved. I have made the password for root empty in /etc/shadow and created a normal "admin" user on the web interface. the sshd denys empty password logins and public-keys, so I logged in as the user "admin" and connected successfully to sshd on the nas. Then I could easily run "su" what made me the root user (root group). Now I change the password with passwd to a secure one and reconnected successfully. Thanks, Gabe!